# How to install hyperledger Fabric on Ubuntu 16 without using dockers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

How do I install hyperledger fabric in ubuntu 16 and run the fabric components as service. How to setup fabric network with multiple hosts multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

While you can build and run the peer and orderer components without Docker, chaincode (what Fabric calls a smart contract) does require its use.

As for how to configure a multi-host network that isn't using Docker Swarm or Kubernetes, you can try out [Hyperledger Cello](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello), which I believe has an option to deploy to VMs.